# How to split the group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

Using Crystal Report 7

Single report (not sub report added, group by id)

```
ID Value total

001 100 2000
002 300 1000
003 400 4000
......
```

I have n number of rows, i want to make first 2 rows subtotal, not each 2 rows, report should display 1st row, 2nd row then 1st & 2nd row subtotal, then 3rd row, 4th row, 5th row to nth  rows....

Expected Ouput

```
ID Value total subtotal

001 100 2000
002 200 3000
-------------------
total 300 5000 0

003 300 1000
......
```

How to do it in crystal report.

Need Crystal Report formula or suggestions

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with [crystal-reports-2008] or [crystal-report-8.5] tags if those versions don't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this formula; substituting actual field for `{table.field}`:

```
//{@stupid group}
If {table.field} IN ['001','002'] Then
  '002'
Else
  {table.field}
```

Insert a group on the formula.